# Passing an AD authenticated php session variable to another page

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I have an AD authentication implemented in login.php, now if the auth is successful I wanted to pass the Users Given name to another php page say app.php.

**login.php**

```
    <?php
     session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $adServer = "ldap://ad.my_domain.com";
    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $ldaprdn = 'my_server' . "\\" . $username;
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);
    if ($bind) {
    $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=my_domain,dc=COM",$filter);
    ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
    {
        if($info['count'] > 1)
        break;
            $_SESSION['user']=$info[$i]["givenname"][0];
            #echo $_SESSION['user'];
            header("Location: app.php");        }
    @ldap_close($ldap);
    } else {
    $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
    echo $msg;
    }

}else{
?>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
    <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the **app.php**

```
             <?php
           session_start();session_regenerate_id();
      ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>My App ::Home Page</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header("Location: login.php"); // If session is not set that redirect to Login Page
      }
    ?>

    // code for app 
    </body>
    </html>
```

AD authentication is successful but somehow the  **$_SESSION['user']**  is not getting passed to app.php. I tried to print the value of $_SESSION['user'] in login.php which is showing the expected result. it is always getting redirected to the login.php from app.php

What am I doing wrong ? Why is isset($_SESSION['user']) failing to get the value passed from login

Comment: not the problem, but you don't need to call `session_regenerate_id` on each page load. Also, you will likely have a problem (and this could be it) when you call `header` and there is output before the call. `header` needs to be called before any script outputs anything. Headers are meant to be sent out before the body of the page. Once there is any output from a page, the headers are done. You can't call header in the middle of a page.

Comment: I have removed `session_regenerate_id ` and also moved header part soon after `session_start`. But no change

Comment: Check your error log. See if you are having any errors.

Comment: Nothing in the error logs/console :(

Comment: Ok, this is what I am getting `PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_reo82dmhrv9pgcen4en3tkbbg3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)`

Comment: I fixed this by giving the needed permission and then it started showing `PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent` This is where it is getting tricky, I had to remove the white space before`<?php session_start();`. And then I got it working ;) This [link was very helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple of troubles but the main reason it was failing because it could not start the session. This was caused by the Whitespace before `<?php` and after `?>` in **app.php**
It took a while for me to figure out this silly but serious thing . Here is a **[good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)**

Hope this helps someone.